# Machine learning dataset correlation

Tags: machine-learning

I have a ML model that has features 1,2,3 and its working perfectly but now I suddenly get a test case with feature 'a' that for which it doesn't show right results how to handle that case? a detailed example would be heart attack prediction system trained for weight ,cholesterol level , height and age ,its working correctly for them but now I have a patient also has diabetes that increases the chances of heart attack. how to improve accuracy based on this uncorrelated new feature ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the new feature and retrain your model.

If your first model is really perfect, you could add a structure to choose models. So if the person does not have diabetes, use the perfect model. Otherwise use another model.

Comment: yes that's one way , but if we get new features every now and then like person has AIDS, person has cancer .. remodelling it every time is not realistic, i was thinking of using the given existing feature and then finding a correlation between the new and old features to increase the probability. for example person with diabetes has 10% more chances of having heart attack so i just increase a probability from 0.4 to 0.45 . I am struggling to find methods to do the same. what's your opinion ?

Comment: For the case of medicines / doctors, the traditional approach of incorporating new features is to execute a study, write, publish and peer-review a paper. This process is way longer than just retraining. If you build your architecture in a smart way, this can be a task of <1h. So saying it is not realistic to invest this time sounds super strange to me.

Comment: actually i was saying from the point of view of user who doesn't know ML, and think of it as a application which is present in user hands he just says that he has diabetes / AIDs /cancer and he wants to know what's the chance of heart attack in that case  . consider 1000 requests/sec 

so i was thinking of alternative ways